# Different brightness for different applications

Tags: ubuntu, display, brightness

Is there any way I can have different brightness levels for different applications on Ubuntu?

When I am using a text editor like Sublime, I have to keep the brightness high to improve readability, but when I switch to browser, I have to decrease the brightness because the browser has lot of white area.